# Is the casting of the Charm Person spell obvious?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, spell-components, charmed

Charm Person has verbal and somatic components.  Is there anything in the rules as written that defines how obvious those verbal and somatic components are?  Would it be obvious the caster was casting a spell from 5 feet away?  From across a crowded room?

I'm specifically interested in an answer based on the rules as written, although interpretation and individual opinion are not unwelcome.

Comment: While the title seems to suggest you're asking about the effect of *charm person* specifically, the body of the question seems specifically interested in whether the components of the spell are obvious - and that question isn't really specific to *charm person*, because many other spells also have V/S components. Could you clarify whether you're asking about the "obviousness" of V/S/M components in general, or asking something else about the obviousness of *charm person* in particular? Do you have a reason to think *charm person* works differently from other spells?

Comment: Sure, maybe?  I liked the reasoning of the selected answer, which suggests that yes, there is actually something special about _charm person_.

Comment: I think the accepted answer actually does a poor job of addressing your question, which seems to be about the components of spellcasting; the other answers address the perceptibility of components directly, whereas the accepted answer only talks about the perceptibility of spell effects. But you can determine for yourself which answer you found most helpful, of course :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, *charm person* is not obvious

In [Chapter 10: Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets) of the rules, the [Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets) section states that spells with subtle effects can be cast without being noticed (PHB, p. 204; emphasis added):

> Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, **a creature might not know it was targeted by a spell at all**. An effect like crackling lightning is obvious, but a more **subtle effect**, such as an attempt to read a creature's thoughts, typically **goes unnoticed**, unless the spell says otherwise.

#### Even the target typically doesn't know

The casting of [*charm person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person) is subtle enough that even the target doesn't know about the spell until it expires (PHB, p. 221):

> When the spell ends, the creature knows it was charmed by you.

If even the target of the spell is unlikely to perceive that it was cast, other observers would have even less of a chance. (A court magician, trained in *Arcana* and watching for such things, would be a different case.)

#### Obvious effects are called out in the spell description

Spells that are obvious when cast call that out in the description. For example, [*knock*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/knock) makes a loud noise that alerts nearby creatures.

#### Social Spells are described in subtle terms

Compare the description of [*burning hands*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/burning-hands):

> As you hold your hands with thumbs touching and fingers spring, a thin
> sheet of flames shoots forth

...to that of [*dominate person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dominate-person)

> You attempt to beguile a humanoid [...]

These descriptions describe what casual onlookers will notice. You can try to charm or beguile someone without magic, it just might not be as effective.

Similar spells provide more detail. The material component of [*friends*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/friends) is described as:

> A small amount of makeup applied to the face as the spell is cast

And after the *friends* spell expires, the target "realizes you used magic to influence its mood" - calling out the effect of the spell, not the components of the casting, as having become obvious.

Lastly, let's consider [*suggestion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/suggestion):

> You suggest a course of action (limited to a sentence or two) and magically influence a creature

In this case the RAW are pretty clear; the physical manifestation of the spell is just that - there's no imp that appears on the target's shoulder to whisper in its ear.

Thus, when the wizard *suggest*s to the head guard, "These aren't the constructs you are looking for," would we really expect the other guards to recognize the "combination of sounds, with specific pitch and resonance" in the old man's voice, and open fire?

#### Enchantment wizards

School of Enchantment wizards gain the ability to make targets of their charms unaware of the spell after it was cast, but there's no mention of the spell-casting itself going from obvious to subtle, which one might assume would be part of the enchanter benefits if it were needed.

#### Illusions

Also, if casting spells were tremendously obvious, many illusion spells would be not so useful.

#### Sorcerer's Subtle Spell Metamagic

Sorcerers have a Metamagic option called Subtle Spell, which allows them to spend sorcery points to cast the spell without verbal or somatic components.

This has the power to make otherwise obvious spells subtle. For example, a manacled and gagged spell caster suddenly transforms into a wolf-man and bursts his bonds. The guards think he's a werewolf, but he just used Subtle Spell and cast the *alter self* and *knock* spells.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm looking for a more RAW answer, and I've edited my question to reflect that.   Your thoughts are welcome, though.

Comment: Thanks. While the RAW doesn't address this directly in the casting a spell section, we can try to extrapolate from other areas (and the other answers have some good points). I would just be careful about being too strict with the magic users in this regard, as it would make their hard-earned spells pretty useless.

Comment: @timster characters won't know *what* spell is being cast, just that it is being cast. Using *major image* to cast an illusion of *animate dead*, *arcane gate*, or any other spell, should look, sound, and feel no different from an actual casting of it. Meaning, even if illusion spells are obviously being cast, the fact that it is an illusion is not obvious.

Comment: @timster - this is a pretty clever analysis.  I never thought to compare the other social spells.

Answer (score 38):

### The act of spellcasting is obvious, but the spell being cast isn't.

The description of [verbal components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#VerbalV) in the rules says:

> Most spells require the **chanting of mystic words**.

And the description of [somatic components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#SomaticS) says:

> Spellcasting gestures might include a **forceful gesticulation** or an **intricate set of gestures**. If a spell requires a somatic component, the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures.

Contrast this with the sorcerer's Metamagic option Subtle Spell, which allows a sorcerer to cast a spell without verbal or somatic components. We can reason that if removing these components makes a spell "subtle", then a spell without those components is *not* subtle.

*Charm person* has a casting time of one action, so it involves around five seconds of non-subtle chanting and forceful and/or intricate gestures with one hand. That sounds like something that would be noticed by someone standing next to the caster.

Generally speaking, I would say that casting a spell with verbal and somatic components is obvious if the caster is being observed, or to anyone standing close to them. For example, it's usually obvious when a spellcaster is casting a spell in combat. But in a crowded, noisy room, people not actively observing the caster might not notice a simple spell being cast.

Seeing that a spell is being cast isn't the same as knowing what the spell is. The rules don't specify how to handle this, but I generally allow an Intelligence (Arcana) check to identify a spell that a character observes being cast, provided they could reasonably know what the spell is. For spells that a character would have no knowledge of, I might allow them some information (e.g. "some kind of powerful invocation") on a successful check.

Comment: My table generally allows a bluff to hide or disguise the spell.

Comment: "Seeing that a spell is being cast isn't the same as knowing what the spell is. The rules don't specify how to handle this" - Note that Xanathar's does have an optional rule for this on p. 85. If someone perceives the casting and/or the spell's effect, they can identify the spell using their reaction as it's being cast (or on a turn after the casting, using their action). They make an Arcana check of DC (15 + spell level); they have advantage if it's cast as a class spell (i.e. not a racial spell or something) and they're a member of that class.

Comment: @V2Blast Thanks, I'll update the answer (which predates XGE by eighteen months) soon.

Comment: @Marq: Did you ever get around to updating the answer? :)

Comment: @V2Blast Apparently not!

Answer (score 14):

## The Components are Obvious, but the Meaning Might Not Be.

Charm Person has verbal and somatic components.  Verbal components are defined as a "particular combination of sounds, with specific pitch and resonance, (which) sets the threads of magic in motion."  Somatic components "might include a forceful gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures", and specifically requires the free use of at least one hand.

Neither of these things seem subtle to my reading.  From 5' away they would be fairly obvious, although from across a crowded room they might be hidden.  In the latter case the people next to the caster would likely observe these actions.

So the actions are obvious, but the meaning may not be.  If bards are rare in the game world and people don't correlate fancy lutes with charms and spells, then perhaps the components will be treated as mere affectations.  But if bards and wizards aren't merely the stuff of legend, even the simple peasants will have heard enough stories about clever bards and powerful wizards to understand that those strange gestures and odd songs are the stuff of magic.  Those stories surely include some mention of the effects - few folks in the standard setting will be surprised that a spellcaster can charm people into strange behaviors.  They will not recognize the specific spell as its cast, but people who witnessed the casting will be on guard, looking for possible effects.

Answer (score 8):

### Verbal and Somatic components are both pretty obvious

Player's Handbook, p. 203, describes the various types of spell components. Of interest to us are:

> Verbal... Most spells require the chanting of mystic words. The words themselves aren't the source of the spell's power; rather, the particular combination of sounds, specific pitch and resonance, sets the threads of magic in motion.
>
> Somatic... Spellcasting gestures might include a forceful gesticulation or an intricate set of gestures

Both chanting and gesticulating forcefully are sound like they would be obvious to someone who was nearby. Across a crowded room they may be less obvious and perhaps a perception check would be appropriate.

### Hiding casting: Stealth and/or Sleight of Hand

If someone does want to perform magic both the Stealth and Sleight of Hand Skills appear to apply. Slight of Hand lists legerdemain as one of its uses which fits perfectly with hiding somatic components. Stealth makes mention of sneaking without being heard so perhaps fits well with masking chanting. Personally I call for a check for each component of the spell (Verbal, Somatic, and Material) since it nicely makes simpler spells easier to hide.

Comment: I like the idea of skill checks. I'm not sure that "combination of sounds, specific pitch and resonance" and an "intricate set of gestures" is necessary obvious to the uninitiated.

Comment: @timster The, "chanting of mystic words", part is what makes it seem obvious to me. Though perhaps intricate gestures gestures could be explained away in a Mediterranean campaign.

Comment: "Sneaking without being heard" means skillful movement so as not to cause a sound. The rules citing that it's not the *words* but the sound of the words that gives the magical effect implies that the sound is *necessary*. I don't see how stealth would let you make sounds without making sound. Sleight of Hand to cover somatic components makes a lot of sense, although again if the gestures and movement are *necessary* you probably couldn't use sleight of hand to make it look like you're doing nothing at all, only to make it look like you're doing something that isn't spellcasting.

Comment: @Ben That's one interpretation of sneaking but I'm happy using a more expansive one that includes masking/disguising the sounds.