# If a creature is immune to being charmed, does it know an attempt to charm it was made?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, immunities

If a creature that is immune to being charmed has a charm spell cast on them. Do they know that an attempt to charm them was made?

Can a creature immune to charm pretend to be charmed by a spell? Or would the caster know the spell failed?

Comment: Definitely related: [Does a spellcaster know when their spell has no effect?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73972/28402)

Comment: Also a related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92261/do-monks-know-when-they-are-charmed

Comment: "Can a creature immune to charm pretend to be charmed by a spell. Or would the caster know the spell failed?" - while these are related to the same topic, they're very different questions to the one in the title. "Does a creature know when something fails to charm it?" is different from "Can a non-charmed creature fake it?" and that's different from "Does a spellcaster know when their spell fails?". (The last one's been previously asked, as Carcer's comment points out.) The second question's different because knowing something tried to charm you doesn't necessarily mean you can feign it.

Answer (score 7):

### Maybe.

Charm says nothing about the target knowing or not knowing an attempt was made. If the target were alerted, the spell or ability would say so, however. Unless the spell was done subtly with metamagic, they may well identify the spell. It's certainly a valid tactic to pretend to be charmed.

Comment: Even if they don't identify the spell, they know a spell was cast and can guess that you are up to shenanigans.

Comment: True, the fact some spell is being cast is obvious.